# How to crop and upload a image using ng-file upload in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, save, crop, ng-file-upload

Hello I am trying to crop my image and upload a image using ng-file upload in angularjs.

I am getting canvas data after cropping. Then how to covert that data to file and upload to server using ng file upload.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also follow this sample on the readme(https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) page for cropping and uploading image: http://jsfiddle.net/xxo3sk41/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to discover this example. I think it's can be help you.

```
$scope.upload = function (dataUrl) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
        data: {
            file: Upload.dataUrltoBlob(dataUrl)
        },
    }).then(function (response) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.result = response.data;
        });
    }, function (response) {
        if (response.status > 0) $scope.errorMsg = response.status 
            + ': ' + response.data;
    }, function (evt) {
        $scope.progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
    });
}
```

[full jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxo3sk41/1/)

Comment: ,A Hello i am getting error in Upload.Upload.dataUrltoBlob(dataUrl)      Thanks in advance

Comment: @JohnRay are you connect all libs to file, that provided in jsfiddle ('External resources tab') ?

Comment: @JohnRay check please thats my answer is right. Thank you!

Comment: ok.. I am trying to post this to nodejs. Any ideal on how to read it in nodejs.?? router.post('/user/uploads', multipartMiddleware, function(req, resp) {

     var newPath = "/Users/testUser/test_hold_files/" + req.files.file.originalFilename;

     fs.writeFile(newPath, req.files.file, function(err) {

         if (err) {
             console.log("Data Error ");
             return console.error(err);
         }

     });

    res.status(200).jsonp({status: "status: success - /Users/testUser/test_hold_files "});
}); ===> this just writes the file name to the folder but its empty.

Comment: Hi.. your code is working file.. but I want to store file in my local system.